# css -webkit, -o, and -moz requirements

Tags: css, webkit

I am running through CSS3 tutorials and I have come across these new requirements. Obviously each browser has different implementations, so you must tell your style sheets to use them. How do you know when a certain browser requires a certain prefix? Is there a single resource that tells you? Is there some sort of magical ultimate include in CSS that will take take of it for you?

Comment: You can always look into to Prefix free: http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On http://caniuse.com it's reported if a CSS property needs the prefix.

Example: http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius you can see that old versions of Safari and Android need the `-webkit-` prefix.

Remember also to place the prefixed properties before the unprefixed one.